# How to save a tuple to some variable from sys.stdin

Tags: python

could you please help how to capture data using sys.stdin

I'd like to save incoming lines to list l, for example.

Incoming data are tuple: `('sometext', 1, 0), ('sometext', 0, 5)`

```
import sys

l = list()

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    l=sys.stdin.read()
    
print(l)
```

Comment: Why are you reading twice? Just do `l.append(line)` inside the loop... But that's not really necessary because `l` is simply the same as `sys.stdin.readlines()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from `sys.stdin` (or by way of `input()` for that matter) simply returns a string; if that string should be turned into something else, you need to parse it or otherwise process it.

If you expect Python expressions, you can use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse each line, but for a simple format like this, you can simply `split` and call `int()` or some other conversion function on the fields which need conversion.

```py
l = list()
for line in sys.stdin:
    if not line.startswith("(") or not line.endswith(")\n"):
        raise ValueError("Not valid input: %s" % line)
    # properly speaking we should only trim one each of left and right paren
    fields = [x.strip() for x in line.lstrip("(").rstrip(")\n").split(",")]
    if len(fields) != 3:
        raise ValueError("Wrong number of fields: %s" % line)
    l.append(tuple([fields[0].strip('"')] + list(map(int, fields[1:]))))
```

This is crude and inelegant, so should at the very least persuade you that there might be a better solution to your problem (maybe just read CSV or JSON instead so you don't have to do all this parsing yourself?)

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I looked for! You are absolutely right that there should be  a better solution of what I'm trying to do. But I'm only at the beginning of learning Python and a lot of obvious things are not so simple for me :) Now I've understood that I choose not the best way to tackle my task from the beginning. But now I'm trying to finish it somehow and then I'll try to do this task some better way. Thanks for detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `input()` built-in function with a slight tweak as below. By doing so, you are left with no imports and clean code.

```
l = list()

while True:
    _in = input()
    if _in.lower() in ('q', 'quit'):
        break
    l.append(_in)

t = tuple(l)
print(t)
```

**Result**

```
$ python run.py 
a
b
c
q
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

However, it is always prescribed to add logs or `print` statements to shed lights on what is going inside the program.

Comment: The question asks about reading `sys.stdin`, why would you revert to `input()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sys.stdin you can use this:

```
import sys

l = []

for line in sys.stdin:

    if len(line) == 1:
        break
    l.append(line[:-1].split())
print(l)
```

The last char in the line is "\n" so if you dont need to save this cut it with

```
line[:-1]
```

like I did.

If the line is empty  (contains only newline char)
`if len(line) == 1 :`
program stops to read stdin.

If the input is tuples at the end you can use:

```
new_l = []
for _ in l:
    new_l.append(tuple(_))
print(new_l)
```

to create new list of tuples.